# backpackforlaravel - Custom function in Controller to Save Data from Ajax Submit Form to DB

Tags: laravel-backpack

I would like to create a function in Controller in order to save the Data to DB.
Here is my situation:

- In my custom view of Show Operation, I have a form.
- I decided to use JQuery AJAX to submit the form to function in Controller.
- In the function in the Controller, I would like to Save the data from the form submit to DB.
- After successfully store data to DB, I would like to retrieve all the data and pass it back to the view

I try to use this concept for the function to save data to DB.

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }

public function store()
{
    $this->crud->request = $this->crud->validateRequest();

    // Encrypt password if specified.
    if ($request->input('password')) {
        $request->request->set('password', Hash::make($request->input('password')));
    } else {
        $request->request->remove('password');
    }

    return $this->traitStore();
}
```

Unfortunately, the record was added to the database with null but echo of $this->crud->request->input('fieldname') contain the value from the form.

Please help me how to fix this problem.

Thanks.